# Can I have my Git 'difftool' apply '--dir-diff' by default?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config

Is there a way to configure Git to always apply the `--dir-diff` option when executing

```
git difftool <commit> <commit>
```

For example, something logically equivalent to:

```
[diff]
    #tool = p4merge
    tool = araxis 

[difftool]
    prompt = false
    dirdiff = true # Is there something equivalent to this?

[mergetool "araxis"]
    path = /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not natively, but you can create a shell alias (depending on what OS you're running) to do that for you, so you'd assign for example `gd` as `git difftool --dir-diff`

Comment: To set it in bash: `git config --global alias.gd '!git difftool --dir-diff'`

Comment: @joozek `gd` already means “git”, so a git alias `git gd` doesn’t make much sense. Serban meant a shell alias: `echo 'alias gd="git difftool -d"' >>.$(basename $SHELL)rc`

Answer (score 0):

Create a git alias: `git config --global alias.gd 'difftool --dir-diff'`

Now `git gd` will run the command you want with fewer characters.